# Obtaining the not intersecting items of dictionaries

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, set, compare

I am trying to compare two list of dictionaries for items that are not common.
All the dictionaries within the lists have common keys:

```
['Name' , 'Title' , 'Status' , 'CECID' , 'Location' , 'Organization', 'Manager' , 'Manager_ID'].
```

`set(newlist1[0].items()) & set(newlist2[0].items())`
produces items which are common to both.
How can I obtain items that are uncommon?

I tried using the `set(a) - set(b)` (difference) operation on the values of the dictionaries. But even then, I am unable to obtain the corresponding key.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`set.symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference):

```
>>> {1,2,3}.symmetric_difference({2,3,5})
set([1, 5])

>>> {1,2,3} ^ {2,3,5}
set([1, 5])
```

`{1, 2, 3}` is a set literal.

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I need both 'key' and 'value' of the differing items whereas this gives the set of different 'values' only.

Comment: @surya, Did you try `set(newlist1[0].items()) ^ set(newlist2[0].items())` ?

Comment: I did. The Set gives the value (['Active'],['Inactive']) (These were the differing values on the 'status' key.) However I needed something like (Status: ['active'])

Comment: [{'Status': 'Active', 'Title': 'ENGINEER', 'Manager': 'Arjun', 'CECID': 'aja', 'Organization': 'xxxxx', 'Manager_ID': 'xxxxx'}] # Similar to this dictionary,around 200 more records will be added to the list.

Comment: @surya, How about this? `set(i for x in newlist1 for i in x.iteritems()) ^ set(i for x in newlist2 for i in x.iteritems())`

Comment: Thanks for the help.But this doesnt work. set([('CECID', 'hms2'), ('CECID', 'krim'), ('Name', 'Krishnadas M'), ('Status', 'Inactive'), ('Name', 'Hari Manayathu MS'), ('Location', 'Delhi')])This is the output.